# Is it possible to have different transitions for the same animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to create an animation with many steps.
I want a different value of transition for each change of style state.

However, using `transition` inside `@keyframes` has no effect.

```css
.square {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: 4s move infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transition: ease-in;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(100%);
    transition: ease-out;
  } 100% {
    transform: translate(0);
    transition: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.6, 1.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

I wonder if there is a way to have different transitions for each stage of an animation without having to combine multiple `animation` in wrapped elements.

Comment: You are allowed to use `animation-easing-function` at each step of your animation, but `transition` won't do anything.

Comment: Yes! I don't know why I always ignored this property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transition` property doesn't do anything inside of keyframes. You can either use the `transition` property to specify how the paint transitions between selectors/transforms (ie, default and `:hover`), or you can use keyframes to specify how it transforms over time range (ie, `from`/`to`, or `0%`, `50%,` `100%` etc).

When you think about it, they're two separate ways of expressing the same information.

You *can* use the `animation-timing-function` property in the individual keyframes if you want more control over transitions. Just know it wasn't supported in Safari (iOS/OSX) until around 2015, so you might run into trouble if you need to support those versions.

Comment: ``animation-timing-function`` is the way. Thanks for the support information too.